# gwt code splitting: is there any benefit in testing whether fragment already loaded or not?

Tags: gwt

In the context of the [GWT Code Splitting Dev Guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) and the suggested module pattern therein to define exclusing code fragments, I understand that the first time the static `Module.createAsync(final ModuleClient client)` is called then the code inside the `Module` class is downloaded and subsequent calls to this static function will not download the same code fragment again.

The pattern further suggests to cache an `INSTANCE` of the `Module` class for "for any code that definitely loads after the module".

So my questions are:

1. After the first call from an initial fragment, does every call to `Module.createAsync(final ModuleClient client)` calls the server to check whether code fragment needs to be downloaded or not?  Or does the call to `onSuccess()` occurs without any server call overhead?
2. Does the following code in an initial fragment causes the `Module` code to be part of the initial download (i.e., not an exclusing fragment)?

>

```
if (INSTANCE == null)
  Module.createAsync(new ModuleClient()
  {
    @Override
    public void onUnavailable(Throwable reason)
    {
      // Action in case of failure
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Module instance)
    {
      instance.showBigComplicatedStuff();
    }
  });
else
  INSTANCE.showBigComplicatedStuff();
```

In other words:

1. Does the existence of `INSTANCE.showBigComplicatedStuff();` in an initial fragment clause causes the `Module` code including `showBigComplicatedStuff()` to be part of the initial fragment or is `Module` going to be anyway in an exclusive fragment because `new Module()` is called within `Module.createAsync` (that is within `GWT.runAsync`)?
2. Does this pattern of calling `Module.createAsync` the first time only when `INSTANCE == null` will help reduce unnecessary asynchronous calls to the server? (Again, I understand that those eventual server calls would not download the corresponding `Module` fragment again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have is incomplete - it isn't obvious why you have `INSTANCE` and `instance`, and if INSTANCE is a public field generated as part of Module.createAsync, can anything else populate it? I'll try to answer both questions on their own, pointing out any assumptions I'm making along the way

1. Assuming that objects of type INSTANCE can never possibly be created outside of a `GWT.runAsync`, the instance method `showBigComplicatedStuff` cannot do anything unless that split point has been loaded (and so at least one instance has been created) - the compiler is smart enough to figure this out. However,
2. The null check is pointless, for exactly the reason you mention - if you understand that there is no server call to go and get the new `GWT.runAsync` fragment, then what async server call do you think is happening inside the `GWT.runAsync`? If the code is downloaded and doesn't need to be downloaded again, then there is nothing to download.

There is no overhead of running a `GWT.runAsync` the second time since the page has loaded. If caching was implemented correctly, even hitting it the first time after the page is loaded *again* should be cheap/free (meaning that the server won't be hit again, but there is still the expense of parsing the JS into memory).

So since `GWT.runAsync` has no server call overhead after it has been loaded (and so `INSTANCE` is non-`null`), you shouldn't need to worry about it. GWT will notice that it already has the code it needs and won't attempt to download it again.

---

Even without so-called 'perfect' caching, this behavior will all hold true. If you happen to be setting caching headers so that your `<hashname>.cache.*` files are cached for a year, then the second time that a module or a split point is loaded, it will continue to use the same local results with no network traffic. If there is no perfect cache but the files are still the same on disk, reloading the app will result in a `304 Not Modified` - not free, but not as expensive as downloading again.

A GWT app (using one of the standard linkers) starts off with a `appname.nocache.js` file - this file contains the `<hashname>` strings mentioned above which only change when code changes, so this must not be cached so that code changes can occur, the client sees the change right away. The initial fragment for a given set of properties (i.e. 'which browser' * 'which locale' * 'which form factor' etc) then is downloaded or read from the cache as `<hashname>.cache.js`, and then when a given splitpoint `<N>` is hit, the split point is fetched as `deferredjs/<hashname>/<N>.cache.js`.

---

With all that said, the theory behind the `Module.createAsync` thing is to be an async factory, so you certainly can use it the way you are describing. In this case though if only having one instance is important, I might have a `getOrCreateAsync` that does the singleton bits inside the module class - as long as the class is responsible for creating the instance and providing it, it might as well always provide it. It really depends on how you are using the instance, what it contains, etc.

Comment: Thanks much for your thorough answer, it makes sense, as I hoped but I was not sure of the mechanism and caching intelligence of `GWT.runAsync`.  So in summary my check whether loaded or not does not hurt the module code split but is useless.  To answer your question, I cache `INSTANCE` following the singleton pattern, so static private with public static Module.getInstance() to access it.  And it is only instantiated within `GWT.runAsync` inside `Module.createAsync`, so all necessary and sufficient assumptions hold.  Again, thanks much.